# How to Solve an ODE by finite element method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Explain how to solve the system of ODE using finite difference method. $u(x,y)$, $v(y)$ and $w(y)$ and $r(y)$ are unknown and $0\leq x\leq1$ and $0\leq y\leq 1$.

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial^2u(x,y)}{\partial x^2}+\dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x}+u(x,y)-v(y)-w(y)=0,\\
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\Bigg\vert _{x=0} = 0,\\
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\Bigg\vert _{x=1}-v(y)=0,\\
-u(0,y)+w(y)+r(y)-r(1)=0,\\
u(1,y)-r(y)+r(1)=1,\\
r^{\prime\prime}(y)=v(y),\\
r^{\prime}(0)=r(0)=0
\end{equation}

I have no ideas about using finite difference element in two directions like PDE or one direction like ODE. Because of just the derivation according to x, I think in one direction is the best. I mean
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial^2u(x,y)}{\partial x^2} = \dfrac{u_{i+1}-2u_i+u_{i-1}}{h} , \dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x}=\dfrac{u_{i+1}-u_i}{h}
\end{equation}
Then, how to use boundary conditions. I am confused.

Comment: Note that you have a PDE: there are *partial* derivatives in there. That makes it epically more complicated. A system of ODEs would be $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=F(f,g,t), \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}=G(f,g,t)$

Comment: Yes, but the derivation is just according to x. However, I think that moving over y can help us to find the solution.

Comment: As a first step you should take your preferred text book and look up the difference between finite difference and finite element methods. The name "Galerkin" should be prominent. In some simple cases both amount to the same, but in general finite elements have a more sound foundation in variational calculus.

Comment: That doesn't help - a PDE is a PDE. Unless there is absolutely no derivative dependence on $y$ at all, in which case what you have is an ODE with a *parameter* $y$. For an actual PDE, you can end up with a grid over space, and then again use difference schemes to iterate over time.

Comment: @obscurans Look at! there is a derivation based on y in one of the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Your boundary conditions (for an IVP at least) are what gives you the values of $u(x_i)$ for some appropriate $i=0$.

Rearrange the equations to find $u_{i+1}$ (I'm using a simpler one, in one dimension):
$$\begin{alignat}{2}&&\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}&=\frac{u(x_{i+1})-u(x_i)}{x_{i+1}-x_i}\\
&\Rightarrow\;&u(x_{i+1})&=u(x_i)+(x_{i+1}-x_i)\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right|_{x=x_i}\end{alignat}$$
This is the actual iteration step that you're going to use.

Having multiple derivatives makes it more annoying, but in the end you're using a Taylor-like approximation centred at $x_i$, and using it (and possibly $x_{i-1}$ and values before it) to compute the next $x_{i+1}$.

There are many different methods out there, with different performance. Specifically for 2 derivatives in 1 dimension, there's also leapfrog integration, where you only calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ at $x_{i+1/2}$, and position $f$ at $x_i$. I suggest reading up a numerical methods textbook.